# Forcing re-evaluation of ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have a header on my application that contains the 'Sign In'/'Create Account' option. When the user logs in I need the aforementioned to swap for the 'Sign Out' option.

However when the user logs in the ui-view changes as expected but doesn't change the header, understandable because it isn't part of the ui-view. Here's my code so far:

```
<ul id="nav-account">
    <li>{{mainCtrl.isAuthenticated ? 'Welcome ' + user.firstname + '!'</li>
    <li ng-if="!isAuthenticated"><a ng-href="{{'HEADER_NAVTABS_SIGNIN'| externallinks}}">Sign In</a> or <a ng-href="{{'HEADER_NAVTABS_CREATE_ACCOUNT'| externallinks}}">Create Account</a></li>
    <li ng-if="isAuthenticated"><a ui-sref="logout">Sign Out</a><li>
</ul>
```

In my controller I'm setting the value of **isAuthenticated** by calling a service:

```
 $scope.isAuthenticated = memberService.isAuthenticated();
```

The only way that the header value will change is if I refresh the whole page - why is this? Shouldn't the ng-if re-evaluate the variable and update the view accordingly?

Does this mean that ng-if is only bound one way? So what can I do to make this work?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: isAuthenticated is a property on scope and its a primitive.  This could be a problem when you change the property later on because if you change it from within a child scope, it will create a copy of the variable on child scope and break the model binding.  To fix this, bind by reference object on scope rather than binding to a primitive on scope. i.e. ng-if="obj.isAuthenticated" and then make sure your object reference (obj) exists on the most outer scope so that it can be inherited by child scopes (i.e. put it on root scope)

Comment: You mentioned that you are setting isAuthenticated by calling a service. What actually is occurring inside `memberService.isAuthenicated()`? It looks like that may potentially be an asynchronous method and how you are using it could be the source of the problem.

Comment: I suggest you [read this awesome article about scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Answer (score 2):

Your controller's code is called only on associated template's load time. This means that the variable **won't be reaffected** later.

However, databinding is valid everywhere including if `ngIf`. To use it and according to explained earlier, I suggest you two simple and clean solutions:

**1.** Bind the **function** (or the service) in your controller's scope:

*Angular:*

```
$scope.isAuthenticated = memberService.isAuthenticated;
```

*Partial:*

```
<li>{{isAuthenticated() ? 'Welcome ' + user.firstname + '!'}}</li>
```

*Note the use of parenthesis: this will let angular evaluate `isAuthenticated()` in each digest loop.*

-

**2.** Bind an authentication **object** in your scope that can be modified by the service:

*Angular:*

```
$scope.auth = memberService.authenticationData;
```

*Partial:*

```
<li>{{auth.isAuthenticated ? 'Welcome ' + user.firstname + '!'}}</li>
```

-

Moreover, like suggested by @Govan, you should prefer directives like `ngShow` rather than manual JS tests:

```
<li ng-show="auth.isAuthenticated">Welcome {{user.firstname}}!</li>
```

Comment: With this solution you still need something to trigger the digest in Angular so that it determines that it needs to check `isAuthenticated()` or `auth.isAuthenticated`.

Comment: Nop. First solution creates a watcher on `isAuthenticated()` which will call the associated function in each digest loop. Second solution will keep the same `$scope.auth` reference all the time, only reaffecting `isAuthenticated` attribute, thus will be detected and updated by Angular.

Comment: @ngasull would you be willing to update your answer please? in the contact of today's angular (9) and users using *ngIf to attempt to protect from pointing to as-yet undefined variables. this is a very common practice and one of the bugs of angular 7 is that it very often does not redraw children dom elements of a *ngIf element that was false on init.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are changing the value as the result of the service call and not some other user-interaction, there is nothing to trigger a digest cycle in angular. In these cases you typically need to wrap the change in $apply to force a digest:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.isAuthenticated = memberService.isAuthenticated();
});
```

For more information see [When to use $scope.$apply](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply())

Comment: As explained in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply() , AngularJS services should be preferred than traditional async + calling `$scope.$apply()`. The reason is to avoid manual digest and let Angular do the maximum event related stuff.

Comment: @blint, I agree with that. This appears to be a situation where those methods are not being used or are being used incorrectly.

Comment: This answer helped me to evaluate async call and I couldn't find any way to do it any other place.